# Crash after performing random forest using enmap box and dzetsaka

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, random-forest, machine-learning, enmap-box

i want to perform random forest classification using tools like dzetsaka and enmap box on qgis 3.2 version but after classification completes upto 50 percent qgis crashes what can be the issue